# Can't resize Scratch window

Tags: 12.04, window

Whenever I try to resize the Scratch window, it turns black as below and slowly reduces in width until it's a line on the screen.

[image]

If I try to maximise the window, it also turns black but the width doesn't reduce. However, when I minimize/unmaximize it, it behaves as when I try to resize it.

I cannot close the window once this happens and have to do it from system monitor.

Anyone know the cause of this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://forum.world.st/Shrinking-windows-when-Scratch-is-run-on-4-4-7-2357-VM-Ubuntu-12-04-64bit-td4633392.html) which suggested to me the following work around. In the file /usr/bin/scratch I modified the line

`VMOPTIONS="-encoding UTF-8 -vm-display-x11 -xshm -plugins /usr/lib/scratch/plugins/:$SQ_DIR/"`

to look like this (i.e. I removed the -xshm flag)

`VMOPTIONS="-encoding UTF-8 -vm-display-x11 -plugins /usr/lib/scratch/plugins/:$SQ_DIR/"`

This doesn't fix the bug but let's you forget about it. Hope it helps.

Kind regards,

/Adam

Comment: Worked for me on a 64 bit machine. Thanks.